# Why do I get an 'unsatisfiable' error when solving a 9x9 Sudoku puzzle?

Tags: minizinc

I am new to minizinc problem-solving. I tried the 9x9 sudoku puzzle problem but can someone kindly explain to me why I get the "unsatisfiable" error here in the below code.

in the beginning, I have written the predefined variables that were already given in the question.

this is the code I've written per the basic syntax provided by my professor.

```
include "alldifferent. mzn";

a2=6;
a4=1;
a6=4;
a8=5;
b3=8;
b4=3;
b6=5;
b7=6;
c1=8;
c9=6;
d1=8;
d4=4;
d6=7;
d9=6;
e3=6;
e7=3;
f1=7;
f4=9;
f6=1;
f9=4;
g1=5;
g9=2;
h3=7;
h4=2;
h6=6;
h7=9;
i2=4;
i4=5;
i6=8;
i8=7;

" here the variables have been defined "

var 1..9: a1;
var 1..9: a2;
var 1..9: a3;
var 1..9: a4;
var 1..9: a5;
var 1..9: a6;
var 1..9: a7;
var 1..9: a8;
var 1..9: a9;

var 1..9: b1;
var 1..9: b2;
var 1..9: b3;
var 1..9: b4;
var 1..9: b5;
var 1..9: b6;
var 1..9: b7;
var 1..9: b8;
var 1..9: b9;

var 1..9: c1;
var 1..9: c2;
var 1..9: c3;
var 1..9: c4;
var 1..9: c5;
var 1..9: c6;
var 1..9: c7;
var 1..9: c8;
var 1..9: c9;

var 1..9: d1;
var 1..9: d2;
var 1..9: d3;
var 1..9: d4;
var 1..9: d5;
var 1..9: d6;
var 1..9: d7;
var 1..9: d8;
var 1..9: d9;

var 1..9: e1;
var 1..9: e2;
var 1..9: e3;
var 1..9: e4;
var 1..9: e5;
var 1..9: e6;
var 1..9: e7;
var 1..9: e8;
var 1..9: e9;

var 1..9: f1;
var 1..9: f2;
var 1..9: f3;
var 1..9: f4;
var 1..9: f5;
var 1..9: f6;
var 1..9: f7;
var 1..9: f8;
var 1..9: f9;

var 1..9: g1;
var 1..9: g2;
var 1..9: g3;
var 1..9: g4;
var 1..9: g5;
var 1..9: g6;
var 1..9: g7;
var 1..9: g8;
var 1..9: g9;

var 1..9: h1;
var 1..9: h2;
var 1..9: h3;
var 1..9: h4;
var 1..9: h5;
var 1..9: h6;
var 1..9: h7;
var 1..9: h8;
var 1..9: h9;

var 1..9: i1;
var 1..9: i2;
var 1..9: i3;
var 1..9: i4;
var 1..9: i5;
var 1..9: i6;
var 1..9: i7;
var 1..9: i8;
var 1..9: i9;

" the constraints are mentioned for all the variables "
constraint alldifferent([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,]);

constraint a1 != a2;
constraint a1 != a3; 
constraint a1 != a4;
constraint a1 != a5;
constraint a1 != a7;
constraint a1 != a8;
constraint a1 != a9;

constraint b1 != b2;
constraint b1 != b3; 
constraint b1 != b4;
constraint b1 != b5;
constraint b1 != b7;
constraint b1 != b8;
constraint b1 != b9;

constraint c1 != c2;
constraint c1 != c3; 
constraint c1 != c4;
constraint c1 != c5;
constraint c1 != c7;
constraint c1 != c8;
constraint c1 != c9;

constraint d1 != d2;
constraint d1 != d3; 
constraint d1 != d4;
constraint d1 != d5;
constraint d1 != d7;
constraint d1 != d8;
constraint d1 != d9;


constraint e1 != e2;
constraint e1 != e3; 
constraint e1 != e4;
constraint e1 != e5;
constraint e1 != e7;
constraint e1 != e8;
constraint e1 != e9;

constraint f1 != f2;
constraint f1 != f3; 
constraint f1 != f4;
constraint f1 != f5;
constraint f1 != f7;
constraint f1 != f8;
constraint f1 != f9;

constraint g1 != g2;
constraint g1 != g3; 
constraint g1 != g4;
constraint g1 != g5;
constraint g1 != g7;
constraint g1 != g8;
constraint g1 != g9;

constraint h1 != h2;
constraint h1 != h3; 
constraint h1 != h4;
constraint h1 != h5;
constraint h1 != h7;
constraint h1 != h8;
constraint h1 != h9;

constraint i1 != i2;
constraint i1 != i3; 
constraint i1 != i4;
constraint i1 != i5;
constraint i1 != i7;
constraint i1 != i8;
constraint i1 != i9;






solve satisfy;


output[show(a1), 
       show(a2), 
       show(a3),
       "|",
       show(a4), 
       show(a5), 
       show(a6),
       "|",
       show(a7), 
       show(a8), 
       show(a9),
       "\n",
       show(b1), 
       show(b2), 
       show(b3),
       "|",
       show(b4), 
       show(b5), 
       show(b6),
       "|",
       show(b7), 
       show(b8), 
       show(b9),
       "\n",
       show(c1), 
       show(c2), 
       show(c3),
       "|",
       show(c4), 
       show(c5), 
       show(c6),
       "|",
       show(c7), 
       show(c8), 
       show(c9),
       "\n",
       show(d1), 
       show(d2), 
       show(d3),
       "|",
       show(d4), 
       show(d5), 
       show(d6),
       "|",
       show(d7), 
       show(d8), 
       show(d9),
       "\n",
       show(e1), 
       show(e2), 
       show(e3),
       "|",
       show(e4), 
       show(e5), 
       show(e6),
       "|",
       show(e7), 
       show(e8), 
       show(e9),
       "\n",
       show(f1), 
       show(f2), 
       show(f3),
       "|",
       show(f4), 
       show(f5), 
       show(f6),
       "|",
       show(f7), 
       show(f8), 
       show(f9),
       "\n",
       show(g1), 
       show(g2), 
       show(g3),
       "|",
       show(g4), 
       show(g5), 
       show(g6),
       "|",
       show(g7), 
       show(g8), 
       show(g9),
       "\n",
       show(h1), 
       show(h2), 
       show(h3),
       "|",
       show(h4), 
       show(h5), 
       show(h6),
       "|",
       show(h7), 
       show(h8), 
       show(h9),
       "\n",
       show(i1), 
       show(i2), 
       show(i3),
       "|",
       show(i4), 
       show(i5), 
       show(i6),
       "|",
       show(i7), 
       show(i8), 
       show(i9)];
```

Comment: Here's a hint: Please check how the `alldifferent` constraint is applied here compared to the rules of Sudoku. If you comment that constraint there's a lot of solutions.

Comment: Check sudoku model in minizinc handbook (https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.4/en/modelling2.html#conditional-expressions). Listing 2.2.5.